# Clear multipale routes from here map in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

I'm doing clear HERE MAP like this, but it doesn't work for me:

```
for (int i=0; i<self.NewMapRoute.count; i++)
{
     self.route = self.NewMapRoute[i];

     self.mapRoute = [NMAMapRoute mapRouteWithRoute:self.route];
     [self.mapView removeMapObject:self.mapRoute];
}
```

previously i added map route like this.

```
for (int i=0; i<self.NewMapRoute.count; i++)
{
      self.route = self.NewMapRoute[i];

      self.mapRoute = [NMAMapRoute mapRouteWithRoute:self.route];
      [self.mapRoute setColor:[arrycolor objectAtIndex:i]];
      [self.mapView addMapObject:self.mapRoute];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove map object that you just created. It doesn't matter if the object was created with the same `route`. You need reference to the previously added `NMAMapRoute`. I don't see an API on `NMAMapView` to get the current list of added map objects so you probably have to manage this list yourself.

Comment: please check my updated question let me know what i'm missing or what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: My answer is still valid. You have to store in some array objects that you assign to the `self.mapRoute` property. And later you need to remove those exact objects.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tobol. putting  self.mapRoute in separate array and for clear routes called removeMapObjects for this array.